# Does reality depend on us observing it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

I have read several articles about quantum physics, concluding that when Einstein said “Do you really believe the moon is not there when you are not looking at it?”, he was ultimately wrong.

Does that mean that the moon exists dependent on human observation? How is that possible? Humans are powerful but surely not that powerful that they can make things appear just by looking.

Answer (score 3):

The existence of the moon clearly doesn't depend on *direct* observation. If it did, the tides would get all messed up if there wasn't someone looking up at all times. That is a provable, and disproven, statement.

You could extend the notion of 'observing,' and imagine that the moon (or some other object) does not exist when there is no record of it escaping to the rest of the universe. Of course, this might essentially never happen for a large object like the moon, that is constantly bombarded by light and cosmic rays and so on, but it is a valid thought experiment. But this is just a modern refinement of the famous philosophical problem "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?" and it is not something that is within the realm of science, quantum or otherwise, which only hopes to describe observations.

Observation, in the generalized sense of when one system records information about another, does play a role in quantum theory that has no parallel in classical physics, which is why Einstein might have been asking such a question. I can't fully explain this role within the confines of this answer. However, this role does not in any way imply that things disappear when humans or sentient observers or whatever are not perceiving them.

Answer (score 0):

The moon, and the rest of our macroscopic universe, exists independent of our observation of it. To see why, consider the Hubble Space Telescope.

Without human intervention, it is capable of capturing photons from distant objects in space, converting those photons to electrical impulses, converting those impulses to digital data, encoding that data in a radio transmission to earth where the radio signal is received, the data stream deconvolved from the radio signal, the digital data converted into electrical impulses, those impulses stored on a hard drive, then downloaded, converted to RGB format, buffered into an image, displayed on an LCD screen from which photons then enter your eye, generate nerve impulses, get sent to your visual cortex, and interpreted by your conscious brain into a representation of a galaxy.

OK, so at what point in this process does the "observation" occur? In your brain. Does that mean that before you look at the image on your computer screen, the data on the hard drive isn't there, or that Hubble itself doesn't exist? Of course not.

Now the situation with objects as small as individual atoms is different, in that at extremely small length scales, our observational equipment cannot detect a photon without affecting it in some manner- in stark contrast to the situation with macroscopic objects like satellites and 10 billion-year-old light beams from galaxies.